# MySql -sorting results- AND issue

Tags: mysql

I have `table1` as below, with two columns:

```
id name1
1  x
2  y
1  y
2  x
3  b
4  f
```

As an outcome I need to see id numbers containing both x and y.  (Which is 1 and 2 in this case.)  Using AND operator does not seem to work.  Is there any way I could fix it?

```
select id 
from table1
where name1=x AND name1=y;
```

Comment: Can 'x' exist more than once for the same ID?

Comment: Yes x can exist more than one time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it using `group by` and `having`

```
select id
from Table1
where name1 in (x,y)
group by id
having count(*) =2
```

if `x` or `y` are repeated more than once for a given id

```
select id
from Table1
where name1 in (x,y)
group by id
having sum( name1=x ) > 0
       and sum(name1=y) >0
```

Comment: See my comment on the question. There is a potential problem with this solution depending on the data.

Comment: @ConradFrix, i agree, will clarify in the answer.

Comment: Thank you radar.This should be the cure.

Comment: @NastrUK, glad it helped. accept the answer to close out the question.

Comment: I think `HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT name1) = 2` would be a better approach than two SUMs [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42b7e/4)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use OR instead of AND

Comment: OR will come up with different result than the one I expect.It will return all IDs with only either x or y.

Comment: ok, then I didn't understand your question 100% correctly.
In that case, radar's answer should work. I didn't see his answer because we were answering at the same time.